# How to run wolfram code from the finder in macos?

Tags: files-and-directories, scripting, mac-os-x, external-calls, system

I'd like to run wolfram code (probably a .wls script) on a file or set of files by selecting them in the finder and using `Right-click > Services`.

For example, long ago I made a convenient service with Automator and Python to convert any selected images to jpeg:

[image]

An answer here would make for a very useful tutorial!

---

#### Update 1 (Response to @xslittlegrass's solution)

I got your solution to run directly in the terminal and also with the play button in the Automator app. But after I saved the workflow in ~/Library/Services/ and tried to use it from right click menu > service > workflow nothing seems to happen... Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve that using the [wolframscript](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html) and Automator:

1. Create a automator script with two steps: a) "Get Selected Finder items" and b) "Run Shell Script"

[image]

2. Define the Wolfram code in the file.wls. Here I'm using a simple example of combining two image files.

   #!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/wolframscript
   files = DeleteDuplicates[$ScriptCommandLine[[2;;-1]]];
   dir = FileNameTake[First@files, {1, -2}];
   Export[FileNameJoin[{dir,"combined.png"}],ImageCollage[Import/@files]];
3. Run the code through finder

[image]

Comment: Plz see my update above.

Comment: @M.R. Did you have the "Get Selected Finder items" step in the automator script? For me, it appears in the right click menu, not the sub-menu of Service.